# Ruby redirect to same page and show errors if form input is bad

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Forgive me I'm new at Ruby. I am trying to create a site to contain information about a zoo.

I have an `enclosure` model and an `animal` model.

This is my code for the `create` method in `animal_controller`

```
def create
    if params.has_key?(:enclosure_id)
        @enclosure = Enclosure.find(params[:enclosure_id])
        @animal = Animal.new(animals_params)
        @animal.user_id = current_user.id

        if @animal.save
           @enclosure.animals.push(@animal)
           redirect_to enclosure_path(@enclosure)
        else
           # ????
        end
    else
        @animal = Animal.new(animal_params)
        @animal.user_id = current_user.id
        if @animal.save
           redirect_to @animal
        else
           render 'new'
        end
    end
end
```

I then have two places where a new animal can be created. One is using a form at `localhost:3000/animals/new`. The other is using a similar form on the `show` page of a particular enclosure, so for example at `localhost:3000/enclosures/1/`

In my code above, I check for the presence of `enclosure_id` to determine where the call is coming from. If the parameter is found, I add the animal to the enclosure there and then. However, if `@animal.save` fails, I do not understand how I can return to the `localhost:3000/enclosures/id` page with the validation error messages being passed. In the case of no `enclosure_id`, `render 'new'` takes the user back to the `../animal/new` page with error messages passed as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's a good idea to go to an other page, because you will have to serialize errors linked to the model and it's gonna be complicated and ugly.

I think you should render the show page of the enclosure and then display the errors

```
#....
    if @animal.save
       @enclosure.animals.push(@animal)
       redirect_to enclosure_path(@enclosure)
    else
       render 'enclosures/show'
    end
#....
```

Comment: This takes me to the right page. However, I don't think the `show` method is called in the `enclosure` controller? That could be a problem

Comment: what resources do you set in `enclosure`'s `show` action ? you need to set them before 'render' here. if it is only `@enclosure`, it's already set and you don't need to worry